# Cannot read properties of undefined problem in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

**I am tring to create a user in my database by letting user signup.**

**when i enter the data manualy in create method it works, like that**

note: the schema componants is {userName:String , number:String , email:String , Password:String}

```
exports.Signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newUser = await User.create({
    userName: 'YoussefAdel',
    number: '12345678948',
    email: 'youssef@gmail.com',
    password: '123456789',
  });

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      user: newUser,
    },
  });
});
```

**But when i try to take the data from the req.body comming from postman the data is readed as undefined**

```
exports.Signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const newUser = await User.create(
  {   userName: req.body.userName,
      number: req.body.number,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
  });

  res.status(201).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      user: newUser,
    },
  });
});
```

and this is the error in postman
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading &#39;userName&#39;)`

i really need help as iam stuck in this problem for 2 days

i tried to replace those lines in the signup method

```
      userName: req.body.userName,
      number: req.body.number,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
```

with `req.body`
and the problem is still the same

this is the json code that i post the request with through postman

```
{
    "userName" : "YoussefAdel",
    "number" : "12345678948",
    "email" : "youssef@gmail.com",
    "password" : "123456789"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body-parser` was marked as deprecated.

Try use:

```js
// JSON
app.use(express.json());
// x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencode({extended: false}));
```

Comment: thank you man <3 this line fixed my problem